# MySQL Separate 1 column VARCHAR into 2 columns of type INT. I've Error 1292 Truncated incorret DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to separate the information from a VARCHAR column `SampleID` into two columns of type INT `ID` and `Ampola`.

I'm using the CAST and SUBSTRING_INDEX functions.

I tried a 'Update' with 'CAST' and 'SUBSTRING_INDEX', but no success.

I want transform `306465-14` into  `ID = 306465` and `Ampola = 14` or `306466` into  `ID = 306466` and `Ampola = 1`, but ignore when `SampleID` isn't valid.

Below is the table dump and the querys I'm trying to use.

```
CREATE TABLE `peak` (`SampleID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`Ampola` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`SampleID`));
INSERT INTO `peak` VALUES ('306465-14',NULL,NULL)
                            ,('306465-15',NULL,NULL)
                            ,('306466',NULL,NULL)
                            ,('TESTE',NULL,NULL)
                            ,('TESTE-02',NULL, NULL)
                            ,('off-0101-2020', NULL,NULL);
```

With SELECT works fine:

```
SELECT SampleID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SIGN(SampleID) = 0 THEN NULL
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) = 0 THEN NULL
        WHEN INSTR(SampleID, '-') = 0 AND SIGN(SampleID) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
    END AS ID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN INSTR(SampleID, '-') = 0 AND SIGN(SampleID) = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 2), '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
    END AS Ampola
FROM Peak;
```

Result:[image]

But with UPDATE query

```
UPDATE Peak
SET ID = 
CASE 
    WHEN SIGN(SampleID) = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN INSTR(SampleID, '-') = 0 AND SIGN(SampleID) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
END, 
Ampola = 
CASE 
    WHEN INSTR(SampleID, '-') = 0 AND SIGN(SampleID) = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SampleID, '-', 2), '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
END
```

Error Message:

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '306465-14'

Thanks to @Strawberry for the simplicity tips.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this a long-winded way of asking how to split a string on a given character? E.g. `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('306465-14','-',1)m,SUBSTRING_INDEX('306465-14','-',-1) n;`

Comment: @Strawberry Yes I think so, now I tidied the question, I think you probably answered it

Comment: @Strawberry For a SELECT works fine, but no with a UPDATE

Comment: `UPDATE my_table SET m = SUBSTRING_INDEX(x,'-',1), n = SUBSTRING_INDEX(x,'-',-1);`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example, which has the advantage of being both minimal and complete...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(x VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,m INT NULL
,n INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('306465-14',NULL,NULL),
('306465-15',NULL,NULL);

UPDATE my_table SET m = SUBSTRING_INDEX(x,'-',1), n = SUBSTRING_INDEX(x,'-',-1); 

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----------+--------+------+
| x         | m      | n    |
+-----------+--------+------+
| 306465-14 | 306465 |   14 |
| 306465-15 | 306465 |   15 |
+-----------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity! In fact, with clean and simple records it works. Some kind of dirt in SampleID in the original table causes the error message. There are data like 'TEST', 'off-2020-01-14', 'off'.

Comment: Feel free to amend the question accordingly, but take my lead and keep it simple. If `Area`, `Height`, `DataInclusao`, `DataAlteracao`, `UsuarioInclusao`, etc., aren't part of the problem, don't make them part of the problem.

Comment: I changed the question. I hope it gets simpler and clearer. Thanks again. And @RiggsFolly, thanks for first edit question.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how my answer fails to address the issues raised

Comment: Maybe you missed that part "I want transform `306465-14` into `ID = 306465` and `Ampola = 14` or `306466` into `ID = 306466` and `Ampola = 1`, but ignore when `SampleID` isn't valid."

Comment: Right - is 12345 a valid sample id?

Comment: Yes. Any not number except '-' is invalid.

Comment: OK, what about 123-456-1?

Comment: Just 'NNNNn' or 'NNNn-Nn'.